# Fastest way to count element in a list satisfying conditions

Tags: python

I want to get the number of elements in a list satisfying certain conditions specified by another list. The way I did is using `sum` and `any`. The simple testing codes are:

```
>>> x1 = list(xrange(300))
>>> x2 = [random.randrange(20, 50) for i in xrange(30)]
>>> def test():
        ns = []
        for i in xrange(10000):
            ns.append(sum(1 for j in x2 if any(abs(k-j)<=10 for k in x1)))
        return ns
```

Using [Profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) shows that the `sum` and `any` caused the most time, any way to improve this?

```
>>> cProfile.run('ns = test()')
     8120003 function calls in 0.699 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.003    0.003    1.552    1.552 <pyshell#678>:2(test)
   310000    0.139    0.000    1.532    0.000 <pyshell#678>:5(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.552    1.552 <string>:1(<module>)
  7490000    0.196    0.000    0.196    0.000 {abs}
   300000    0.345    0.000    1.377    0.000 {any}
    10000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    10000    0.016    0.000    1.548    0.000 {sum}
```

The function `test` only contain 10000 iterations. Generally, I would have tens of thousands iterations, and using the `cProfile.run` shows that this block cause majority of executing time.

===================================================================

**Edit**

According to [@DavisHerring's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668895/3003072) answer, using binary search.

```
from _bisect import *
>>> x1 = list(xrange(300))
>>> x2 = [random.randrange(20, 50) for i in xrange(30)]
>>> def testx():
        ns = []
        x2k = sorted(x2)
        x1k = sorted(x1)
        for i in xrange(10000):
            bx = [bisect_left(x1k, xk) for xk in x2k]
            rn = sum(1 if k==0 and x1k[k]-xk<=10
                 else 1 if k==len(x1k) and xk-x1k[k-1]<=10
                 else xk-x1k[k-1]<=10 or x1k[k]-xk<=10
                 for k, xk in zip(bx, x2k))
            ns.append(rn)
        return ns
```

According to `cProfile.run`, `0.196 seconds` is reached, 3x+ faster.

Comment: I don't think you are interpreting the results correctly. From the manual page you cited, 'cumtime' includes time spent in subfunction calls so its not reasonable to say that 'sum' was amongst the calls that took the most time. For what you are asking, I would suggest 'tottime' as the better metric, and thus 'any' and 'abs' are the top 2 users.

Comment: What benefit do you derive from using `abs()` in this situation?

Comment: Try using a list comprehension to build `ns`—which are often faster than repeated `append()` method calls.

Comment: @Rolf this is just a simple example. In practice, for any element in `x2`, I want to use absolute error to find whether any element in `x1` has difference between the two elements less than this error. Then count the number of elements in `x2` having the answer of yes.

Comment: Are actual list element scalars or vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nature of your predicate is critical; because it is a distance along a line, you can give your data a corresponding structure to speed the search.  There are several variations:

Sort the list `x1`: then you can use binary search to find the nearest values and check whether they’re close enough.

If the list `x2` is much longer, and most of its elements are not in range, you can make it a bit faster by sorting it instead and searching for the beginning and end of each acceptable interval.

If you sort both lists, you can step through them together and do it in linear time.  This is asymptotically equivalent unless there’s another reason to sort them, of course.

Comment: Thanks. Significant improvement is achieved. I have edited my question to include the implementation of your suggestion by using [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#module-bisect). But I have to iterate through `x2` two times and use several `if ... else..` to check the index obtained by `bisect_left`. Any further optimization of the search/codes exists?

Comment: @Elkan: You can start by writing `sum(k>0 and xk-x1k[k-1]<=10 or k<len(x1k) and x1k[k]-xk<=10)`.  It _might_ help to make a (local) function that called `bisect_left` which you could apply with `map`.

Answer (score 0):

### The code

Use an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) data structure. A very simple implementation suitable for your needs could be as follows:

```
class SimpleIntervalTree:
    def __init__(self, points, radius):
        intervals = []
        l, r = None, None
        for p in sorted(points):
            if r is None or r < p - radius:
                if r is not None:
                    intervals.append((l, r))
                l = p - radius
            r = p + radius
        if r is not None:
            intervals.append((l, r))
        self._tree = self._to_tree(intervals)

    def _to_tree(self, intervals):
        if len(intervals) == 0:
            return None
        i = len(intervals) // 2
        return {
            'left': self._to_tree(intervals[0:i]),
            'value': intervals[i],
            'right': self._to_tree(intervals[i + 1:])
        }

    def __contains__(self, item):
        t = self._tree
        while t is not None:
            l, r = t['value']
            if item < l:
                t = t['left']
            elif item > r:
                t = t['right']
            else:
                return True
        return False
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
x1 = list(range(300))
x2 = [random.randrange(20, 50) for i in range(30)]
it = SimpleIntervalTree(x1, 10)
def test():
    ns = []
    for i in range(10000):
        ns.append(sum(1 for j in x2 if j in it))
    return ns
```

### What the code does

In `__init__`, the list of points is first transformed to a list of contiguous intervals. Next, the intervals are put in a balanced [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree). In that tree, each node contains an interval, each left subtree of a node contains lower intervals and each right subtree of a node contains higher intervals. This way, whenever we want to test whether a point is in any of the segments (`__contains__`), we perform binary search starting from the root.